# How do you create a new site template for my sites?

Tags: sharepoint

We've created a new site template for sites in general.

However how do we implement the same site template for users my sites?
They appear to work completely differently.

Does anyone how pointers on how to do this?

Extra Detail:
This is for Sharepoint 2007, standard edition.

Comment: Are you talking about a Sharepoint template, or a Sharepoint master page?

Comment: "How do you create a new site template for my sites?"  Well, first we negotiate a contract, you cut me a check, then I go to work.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link explains how to do it:

[Customizing MOSS 2007 My Sites within the enterprise](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/03/22/customizing-moss-2007-my-sites-within-the-enterprise.aspx)

The blog post above, is the predecessor to part of the Community Kit for Sharepoint.

See:

[MySiteCreate 1.0 Production](http://www.codeplex.com/CKS/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2824)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Sharepoint? And, are you looking for something like this? From the MSDN site:

[Branding a Sharepoint Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms916822.aspx)
and
[About Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms916822.aspx#office_sharepointapplyingcorporatebrand_abouttemplates)
and
[Customizing Sharepoint Sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms916801.aspx)

Should at least get you situated or serve as a launch point to get you the information you need.

Comment: Ah, the links will point you to 2003 articles.

See this link for a set of MOSS 2007 articles:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb693442.aspx